# Dynamic/interactive slideshows in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, slideshow

I'm trying to display a full-screen slideshow, but some of the slides will have internet-enabled/interactive content (news, weather, twitter trends). Is there any software package or combination thereof that I may use to do this? Currently, I'm rendering a video from a slideshow program (iPhoto on Mac OS X), and transferring that to my machine & playing it fullscreen with VLC, but that doesn't allow for interactive or dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LibreOffice Impress to do that..
This link explains how to have live data in Impress presentations:

> http://cdriga.kfacts.com/open-source-world/openofficeorg/remote-images-in-your-openofficeorg-impress-presentations/2007/10/31/

Although the article talks about OO Impress, the LibreOffice Impress also works the same way...